# Sending messages to multiple contacts using Intent

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm trying to send messages through in built sms app through Intent. Its working fine. Here is my code

```
public class Main_Act extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(sendSMS()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Act.this, Sample.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}

protected boolean sendSMS() {
    ArrayList<String> nums = new ArrayList<String>();
    nums.add("111111111");
    nums.add("222222222");
    Log.i("Send SMS", "");
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.putExtra("address"  ,nums);
    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body"  , "Test ");

    try {
        startActivity(smsIntent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Main_Act.this,
                "SMS faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

But the problem is it gets navigated to another activity without clicking send button in sms application. It should goto another activity only after clicking the send button in messaging app. Can anyone help me with this problem, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove your intent in onClick method only just call sendSMS ()

Comment: yeah... even I tried that but where should I put the code for navigating to other activity after clicking send button in message app

Comment: Create a another  method for newActivity launching and call after sendMessage

Comment: its not working... it just goes to another activity even though I didn't click send button in in-built messaging app

Answer (score 3):

Let's clear out a slight misunderstanding in your code:
You should not try to start both intents in the same part/run of the code as you do here.

A startActivity will not execute directly going to the activity and then return to the same place in the code when activity execution finishes. In stead it asynchronously **queues** the intent for execution. Then your code queues another intent for execution. After the current code finishes (in this case when the button onClick() method ends) Android queue mgmt can start picking off the queue. Probably the first intent is executed shortly and then directly overrun by an immediate execution of the second.

So what happens in summary is that you first add one intent to the queue in sendSMS and then add intent 2 to the queue in onClick, before leaving. **Now** both the intents are executed.

What you need to do is to change the sendSMS code to something like:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address"  ,nums);
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body"  , "Test ");
// To force the SMS app to return immediately after sent SMS
smsIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true); 
startActivityForResult(smsIntent, MY_SMS_REQUEST_RESPONSE_CODE);
```

Note the startActivityForResult() method that indicates that we expect Android to return and the "exit_on_sent" extra, to force a swift return.

MY_SMS_REQUEST_RESPONSE_CODE is just any random code you select to recognize the returning result in the callback method (even if you currently do not expect any other returning results, you may have some in the future).

Next thing to do is to remove the second intent creation and queuing. In stead you implement the following callback method (added to this activity):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int callbackIdentifier, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    // Is this the expected sendSMS callback ?
    if (callbackIdentifier== MY_SMS_REQUEST_RESPONSE_CODE) { 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          // Continue where you left off (e.g. execute intent 2)
          Intent intent = new Intent(Main_Act.this, Sample.class);
          startActivity(intent);            
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Error handling/retrying etc
        }
    }
    // Support inherited callback functions
    super.onActivityResult(callbackIdentifier,resultCode,intent);
}
```

Comment: the new activity won't be called because the inner if condition won't be executed as we are not setting any value for RESULT_OK & resultcode is 0

Comment: The RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELED codes should be defined in the Activity class, so if this code resides in your activity it should be defined already.

0 should be the result code RESULT_CANCELED which you also would get if the SMS app does not return directly and the user therefore has to use the back button to get back. Hence the smsIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true); in my code above.

If it still fails to return the proper return code there might be something else missing in my code above. I have not run the code right now.

Comment: RESULT_CANCELED is also what is returned if there are any problems for  Android when executing the intent (security errors, lack of SMS app or similar). I don't think you need any unusual permissions in the manifest to use this solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you want to pass data and type don't call method **separately** because will delete each other you must pass it in one method

wrong

```
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
```

true

```
smsIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("smsto:"),"vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
```